# firebase no permite generar apk en ionic 4

Tags: android, cordova, ionic4

Desde hace unos dias que tengo un problema al generar un apk con ionic, ejecuto el comando

```
ionic cordova build android
```

y me muestra el siguiente error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > Failed to execute aapt
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

y cuando elimino el plugin de firebase si crea el apk, lo curioso es que hace 1 semana que fue la ultima vez que cree una version del apk si lo creo sin problemas y ahora ya no me lo permite, alguien sabe por que pasa esto?

Comment: Mira a ver si es la versión de firebase puede ser que esté dando problemas. Usa la version 4.x de firebase a ver si te funciona

Comment: @EmmanuelDeveloper, ya cambie la version de firebase y aun asi me da ese problema. que otra cosa crees que pueda ser?